# How to add CKEditor plugins client-via side JavaScript?

Tags: ckeditor

Several online services that I use for work incorporate CKEditor (namely, desk.com and targetprocess.com), but neither includes find/replace functionality, because I guess neither knows that it's almost 2017.

I am pretty handy with JavaScript, and I wonder if there's a way to trick CKEditor into using a find/replace plugin such as http://ckeditor.com/addon/find via client-side JavaScript?

Obviously, I don't have access to the source code at either desk.com or targetprocess, and I am willing to "roll my own" until they get around to including it.

Answer (score 1):

If the plugins you are looking for are in fact present on the websites you are using, then you may try destroying the CKEditor instance and starting CKEditor with your own settings e.g. with different toolbar and with plugins enabled via http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins (e.g. using Greasemonkey, by writing a browser extension that works on selected domains etc.)

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for this suggestion. I'll have to snoop around and see if either of the sites has the find plugin wherever they keep their other plugins. This could be a winner, if so.

Otherwise, I guess XSS protections would prevent it from working with the plugin hosted elsewhere.

Comment: As it turns out, neither site has the plugin available. I'll contact them and ask them to incorporate it, but thank you for your help.